# Ruby - local variable gets modified when changing instance variable

Tags: ruby, variables, scope, instance-variables

`temp` gets `@board.dup`, and `@board` array is modified. However, `temp` gets modified as well! I have tried reading all the related documentations but still couldn't figure out an explanation.

```
class Test
    def initialize
        @board = [[1,2],[3,4], [5,6]]
    end

    def modify
        temp = @board.dup #Also tried .clone

        print 'temp: ';p temp
        print '@board: ';p @board

        @board.each do |x|
            x << "x"
        end

        print "\ntemp: ";p temp
        print '@board: ';p @board
    end
end

x = Test.new
x.modify
```

Output:

```
temp: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
@board: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

temp: [[1, 2, "x"], [3, 4, "x"], [5, 6, "x"]] # <= Why did it change?
@board: [[1, 2, "x"], [3, 4, "x"], [5, 6, "x"]]
```

What can I do to ensure temp doesn't get modified?

Comment: It's the same reference, e.g., `temp` is pointing at the same array `@board` is. If you want to maintain the original then you'll have to clone it.

Comment: Sorry, edited my question. I did do `@board.dup` in my code. But temp got changed as well. (also tried with `.clone`, still the same output)

Comment: You have to clone deep.

Answer (score 1):

You have Array with Arrays, so you dup the first array but, inside object point to the same instance. In this case you just modify the same source.

like here:

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3]]
arr2 = arr.dup

arr2[0] << 1

p arr
# => [[1, 2, 3, 1]]
p arr2
# => [[1, 2, 3, 1]]
```

So you must use `dup` for all array instance like this.

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3]]
arr3 = arr.map(&:dup)
arr3[0] << 1

p arr
# => [[1, 2, 3]]
p arr3
# => [[1, 2, 3, 1]]
```

In your case use this `map`.

```
class Test
  def initialize
    @board = [[1,2],[3,4], [5,6]]
  end

  def modify
    temp = @board.map(&:dup) # dup all

    print 'temp: ';p temp
    print '@board: ';p @board

    @board.each do |x|
      x << "x"
    end

    print "\ntemp: ";p temp
    print '@board: ';p @board
  end
end

x = Test.new
x.modify
# temp: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
# @board: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
# 
# temp: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
# @board: [[1, 2, "x"], [3, 4, "x"], [5, 6, "x"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `clone` and `dup` produce a shallow copy. Thus the object ids of the inner arrays are still the same: those are the same arrays.

What you need is a deep clone. There is no built-in method in the standard library able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-dup):

> `dup` produces a shallow copy of obj—the instance variables of obj are copied, but not the objects they reference.

That said: You will need to make a deep-copy of your array.

When you are using the ActiveSupport gem (Rails) you can use its `deep_dup` method instead of just calling `dup`:

```
temp = @board.deep_dup
```

Without gems mashaling might be a easy solution to deep dup almost everything, without knowing about the internals of an object:

```
temp = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(@board))
```

Comment: `Marshal` is OP in this case.

Comment: @LukasBaliak: but there's nothing better in vanilla ruby.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev For full dump all deep object yes, But in this case i think a litle OP.

Comment: @LukasBaliak: I kind of agree with you. But I prefer to write answers that do not only work for a specify example. Other readers in the future might have a slightly different problem and might be interested in a more generalized solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a deep_dup method for nested arrays:

```
class Array
  def deep_dup
    map {|x| x.deep_dup}
  end
end

# To handle the exception when deepest array contains numeric value
class Numeric
  def deep_dup
    self
  end
end

class Test
    def initialize
        @board = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
    end

    def modify
        temp = @board.deep_dup
        ...
    end
end

x = Test.new
x.modify

# temp: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
# @board: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

# temp: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
# @board: [[1, 2, "x"], [3, 4, "x"], [5, 6, "x"]]
```